# Restlet ChallengeResponse null on server side when using GWT

Tags: authentication, gwt, restlet

We're trying to send Google Authentication tokens to our Rest interface on Google App Engine. 
As explained here (under heading "Calling a Google API")

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

We should do this by including an *Authorization: Bearer HTTP header*.
On the client side we're using;

```
public ClientResource getClientResource(Reference pReference, String pAccessToken)
{
    ClientResource lClientResource = new ClientResource(pReference);

    ChallengeResponse lChallengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
    lChallengeResponse.setRawValue(pAccessToken);
    lClientResource.setChallengeResponse(lChallengeResponse);

    return lClientResource;
}
```

So the ChallengeResponse with setRawValue() is used to set the header;

```
ChallengeResponse lChallengeResponse = new        ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
lChallengeResponse.setRawValue(pAccessToken);
lClientResource.setChallengeResponse(lChallengeResponse);
```

For our J2SE clients this is working. Although there's an error message;

*"Challenge scheme HTTP_Bearer not supported by the Restlet engine."*

we're able to read the token on the server side with;

```
ChallengeResponse lChallengeResponse = pRequest.getChallengeResponse();
String lAccessToken = lChallengeResponse.getRawValue();
```

While this is working for our J2SE clients, our GWT clients always return **lChallengeResponse == null**

Is this the correct method to set the *Authorization: Bearer HTTP header* or should we add extra/other configuration options?

Why isn't this working for our GWT clients (return null)?

How do we get rid of the error message on our J2Se clients?